# Fontawesome web fonts not displaying on live sites

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I've been using Fontawesome on my site for a few years now, I have recently updated to Angular 14 & Node 18.

The icons are still showing on my local build, but not on production.

I have downloaded V6 Fontawesome and have embedded this to my project -

Index.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/web-fonts-with-css/css/all.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
```

I have included all the css files from the download as required, hoever I am just getting blank spaces where the icons should be.

I am using Chrome 109.0.5414.119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install font-awesome npm package
2. Add font-awesome css path in `styles` array of angular.json file. It might look like below

```
"styles": [
...
"node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
...
]
```

3. After that you can use it like
   `<em class="fa fa-bars"></em>`

Answer (score 0):

The new update of Fontawesome has moved away from using 'fas-fa' and instead is using 'fa'fa-'.